# Is there a way to cause a Grunt plugin to fail if input files are missing?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I've been working with the [Grunt cssmin plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-cssmin). I had a block in my Gruntfile which looks approximately like this:

```
cssmin: {
    target: {
        files: {
            '<%= config.target %>/mytarget.css': [
                'bower_components/normalize.css/*.css',
                'bower_components/html5-boilerplate/css/main.css',
                '<%= config.src %>/css/*.css'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

For a while this was working fine; but I moved this to another machine and didn't set up my bower components correctly - the `html5-boilerplate/css/main.css` file was missing - and yet the task still completed successfully. In fact, I can put completely fake paths in that array and the minification still completes.

Is there a way, **in general**, to cause Grunt to fail and quit if files are missing from an array like this? (I'm not sure if the files array is a general Grunt concept or one provided by cssmin). If not, is there a way to cause this specific plugin to fail?

(By the way, I am aware that [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) is probably somewhat old-fashioned these days, but I'm in the process of migrating an old site. I've also fixed my Bower install process so that it's run before this step automatically now. I'd still like to understand a more general solution to the problem of missing files, though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the [files array format](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#files-array-format) you can use `nonull: true` to raise a warning if a file doesn't exist:

```
files: [
  {
    src: [
      'a.js',
      'b.js',
    ],
    dest: 'c.js',
    nonull: true
  }
]
```

[Now force Grunt to stop](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.fail) on a warning by wrapping [grunt.log.warn](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-legacy-log/blob/master/index.js#L181) in your own function:

```
var gruntLogWarn = grunt.log.warn;
grunt.log.warn = function(error) {
    gruntLogWarn(error); // The original warning.
    grunt.fail.warn('Stop! Hammer time.'); // Forced stop.
};
```

Above will stop on any warning. But we want to stop if source files are missing. Filter Grunt warnings on 'Source file ... not found.':

```
var gruntLogWarn = grunt.log.warn;
grunt.log.warn = function(error) {
  var pattern = new RegExp("^Source file (.*) not found.$");
  if (pattern.test(error)) {
    grunt.fail.warn(error);
  } else {
    gruntLogWarn(error);
  }
};
```

Comment: This is still not great, as it requires a lot of explicit work with the warning function. But for working round the broken default behaviour of Grunt, it's pretty good - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could create a task that goes *before* `cssmin`.

```
grunt.task.registerTask('checkIfFilesExist','',function(){
  // Check for those files here. Throw if something's wrong.
});

grunt.task.registerTask('checkBeforeDoingStuff',[
  'checkIfFilesExist',
  'cssmin'
]);
```

And iirc, you could reuse the same params in the cssmin task by just referring them via `<% %>`.

Comment: Thanks, this will work, but I don't think it's a good precedent to set. I would need to repeat the list of files in two places (even with params); and I'll need to create one of these tasks for each of the 'real' tasks I have (I'm looking for a generalised solution to make my script more robust).

Comment: Marking this as accepted, since it's the best answer so far. Would still welcome a more generalised solution which doesn't require doubling-up each task...

Answer (score 0):

The Grunt option `nonull: true` is supposed to deal with this, but it doesn't always work with all tasks. For me it works with `htmlmin`, `phpmin` but not `cssmin` and `uglifyJS`.

To trigger an error if a file is missing you can create a [filter](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function) function instead.

```
   var checkFileExists = function(filepath) {
    if (!grunt.file.exists(filepath)) {
      grunt.fail.warn('Could not find file: ' + filepath);
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  };

{ src: ['<%= meta.srcPath %>/index.php'], dest: '<%= meta.deployPath %>/index.php', filter: checkFileExists, nonull: true},
```

With the above script, it now works perfectly with every task I've tested.